# Processing of SQL

Tags: sql

I have a question regarding the processing of SQL code. Which of the following program is more efficient? Or is it same?

My understanding - the second program is more efficient as it subsets data before join

```
select a.custid, b.ref_date,b.status
from customertable a
left join accounts b
on a.custid = b.custid
where '2015-01-01' <= b.ref_date <= '2016-01-01'

select a.custid, b.ref_date,b.status
from customertable a
left join (select * from accounts
where '2015-01-01' <= ref_date <= '2016-01-01') b
on a.custid = b.custid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is a *declarative* language, which means that you tell the systems what results you want and it decides *how* to fetch those results.  So in most cases there's no way to say with certainty whether one query over another will be more "efficient", since the compiler has a lot of leeway in what plan it develops.

That said, your two queries *are not equivalent*.

suppose you had the following data:

```
customertable 
-------------

custid
------
1
2

accounts
--------

custid    refdate     
------    -------     
1         2015-01-01  
2         2014-01-01
```

The results of the first query would not include customer 2, since the `where` clause would filter it out because there is a matching account, but the `refdate` is not in the required range.  The second query would include customer 2, but the `refdate` and `status` would be `null` because the matching account did not satisfy the `join` clause.

The following query *would* be equivalent to your second one:

```
select a.custid, b.ref_date,b.status
from customertable a
left join accounts b
on a.custid = b.custid
  and '2015-01-01' <= b.ref_date <= '2016-01-01'
```

I would not expect a significant difference in efficiency between the two queries, since the plans the compiler comes up with are likely to be identical.

In general, the only way to say with certainty if one query is more efficient that the other is to *try it both ways and measure the results*.  Even then, it may not *always* be more efficient, since changes over time such as data dispersion, efficiency of indexes, and other factors can make one query more efficient *in a given context*.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I apologize i didn't get this part - "your two queries are not equivalent. The first would not include results where there was a matching account with no records between 2015-01-01 and 2016-01-01, while the second would". Could you please explain further? Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: @Riya I added an example.  Understanding the difference between having conditions in the `join` clause and the `where` clause can be tricky.

Comment: @Riya Logically, the joins are completed first and the where clause comes next. The difference is two-fold: A row from the customer might find no match via the join (across the entire table) and then only afterward you look at the date and eliminate that customer because that date value is null (resulting from the left join.) Or there were matches but they all fell outside the date range and so that customer was entirely eliminated the same way. Effectively this becomes an inner join. Conditions on the outer join cannot be freely moved to the `where` clause.